# how to create nodes of different characteristics using a single node class in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes

my node class is

```
class Node{

    protected int data;
    protected Node link;
    public Node(){
      link=null;
      data =0;
    }

    public Node(int d,Node n){
      data=d;
      link=n;  
    }

    public void setlink(Node n){
      link=n;
    }

    public void setData(int d){
      data=d;
    }

    public Node getlink(){
      return link;

    }

    public int getData(){
      return data;
    }
}
```

I want to create a node with 5 parts :

1. to store row no.
2. to store column no.
3. to store value
4. pointer to next row
5. pointer to next column

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. You should explain more detail. If you need different implementations of `Node` just declare subclasses.

Comment: Why don't you add all 5 attribute to class? Now you have only 2 attributes. Will all nodes have these 5 attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following class as node with required values:

```
static class Node
    {
        int rowNo;
        int columnNo;
        int value;
        Node next;
        int nextColumnNo;
        Node(int r,int c,int v) 
        {
            rowNo=r;
            columnNo=c;
            value=v;
            next=null;
            nextColumnNo=0;
        }
    }
```

And use the nodes as follow by linking together:

```
head = new Node(1,11,11);
Node second = new Node(2,22,22);
Node third = new Node(3,33,33);

head.next=second;
second.next=third;

head.nextColumnNo = second.columnNo;
second.nextColumnNo = third.columnNo;
```